# How do I share "/home" itself and give it write acces instead of readonly via Samba

Tags: networking, server, permissions, samba, read-only

I can see my /home directory with Windows 7 machine but I can only read it. There's no write permission.

1. I created a user called *tw8* with this command:

   sudo useradd -g users -G lp [nameofnewuser] -M
2. Converted unix users from Webmin>Servers>Samba Windows File Sharing>Convert Users
3. Created a share https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JfKy.png
4. Security and access control of this share https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlDG9.png
5. Files permissions of this share https://i.stack.imgur.com/aztTR.png

So any ideas what's wrong? Like I said I can browse what ever is inside /home folder but just can't seem to write.

Comment: There are setings for sharing hoe dirs in /etc/samba/smb.conf, basically, you uncomment a few lines, restart samba, and it's done. I hope someone knows what those screenshots are, I've never seen anything like that in Ubuntu, so it is probably something non-default.

Comment: Those screenshots are from Webmin interface.

Comment: Please do NOT share home. I have several horror stories about companies doing that where Windows users did not know what all those files starting with dot are and decided to delete them. I know you know what they are but it is so damn easy to make a mistake where you mess up an important file used for the logging in into that user I would advice to never use /home/ as a share.

Comment: @Rinzwind it's a closed home network.

Comment: @emrecnl so? Windows single user mentality should stay on Windows. In Linux you share a separate directory for users to use; not /home/ You will end up with a broken system whenever anyone from the Windows side decides to remove a crucial file in /home/ (Windows for instance also does not care for the hidden files in /home/*)

Comment: That's not what I am asking. If it gets broken I restore backup image taken with Acronis. However it won't because like I said it's a closed network and I'm the only one accessing this server.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions in Samba are a mix of Samba permissions and unix permissions.  In your case, I suppose the directory `/home` was already created when you decided to share it.  Only, it belongs to a specific user (normally 'root').  You must then grant all users (Unix) write access to that directory.
You can do it by using the Java file manager in webmin, by selecting the `/home` directory and clicking the 'Information' button.  There, modify as appropriate.